# find: equal file size limit but different unit returns different result

Tags: linux, find

I noticed that the these two commands to list files below 5 GiB produce different results:

```
find . -type f -size -5368709120c
find . -type f -size -5G
```

Specifically the one that uses kilobyte unit (`5368709120c`) returns additional files that are larger than the maximum file size returned by the one that uses the GiB unit (`5G`).

From the `find` manual page I read the following:

```
-size n[cwbkMG]
          File uses n units of space.  The following suffixes can be used:
          `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
          `c'    for bytes
          `w'    for two-byte words
          `k'    for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
          `M'    for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
          `G'    for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)

The size does not count indirect blocks, but it does count blocks 
in sparse files that are not actually allocated.  Bear in mind that the `%k'
and `%b' format specifiers of -printf handle sparse files differently.   The 
`b'  suffix always denotes 512-byte blocks and never 1 Kilobyte blocks, 
which is different to the behaviour of -ls.
```

So, given that the unit of `G` is 1073741824, `5G` should be `5368709120c`. Is the issue due to how sparse or indirect blocks are counted?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Kubuntu `man find` states [emphasis mine]:

> `-size n[cwbkMG]`
>   […]
>   The `+` and `-` prefixes signify greater than and less than, as usual. Bear in mind that **the size is rounded up to the next unit**. Therefore `-size -1M` is not equivalent to `-size -1048576c`. The former only matches empty files, the latter matches files from 0 to 1,048,575 bytes.

So if a file takes more than 4GiB and less than (or exactly) 5GiB, it will qualify to `-size 5G`. Your `-size -5G` won't match it.

Comment: Thanks. Regrettable that the man page on CentOS does not mention this.