# What is a reliable code (dependable code) to count files using Bash?

Tags: linux, command-line

Counting files ...

Example #1: `ls` code to count directories and    count regular files with  Ubuntu 20.04.3 or specifically
bash50171$

```
ls -1 | wc -l
```

Good news, above `ls` code handles a file name with spaces since it puts single quotes `'  '` around `'file  name'`

Bad news, above `ls` code miscounts: One (1) file with a newline in its file name, counts as two (2) files.

Problem: miscounting files.

Example #2: `ls` code gives correct file count:

```
ls -1qi  | grep -o '^ *[0-9]*' | wc -l
```

Above `ls` command correctly counts files with a newline. Command counts a List of inode numbers.

Above shortened `ls` command is:

```
ls -1qi
```

Correctly shows a file name with spaces using `'  '`. Correctly shows a file name with a newline using `'  '`.

How to create problem files? use:

```
touch 'a b' 'a  b' a$'\xe2\x80\x82'b a$'\xe2\x80\x83'b a$'\t'b a$'\n'b
```

Command recursively, add `R`:

```
ls -1qRi
ls -1qRi | grep -o '^ *[0-9]*'
ls -1qRi | grep -o '^ *[0-9]*' | wc -l
```

Problem:

- When to use `ls` in code?
- When not to use `ls` in code?

Reference A:

Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` [is explained here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In short, parsing `ls` is bad practice.

Reference B:

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) explains why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?

Example #2 code skirts one problem (one snag)
with a file with a newline in its file name.

```
ls -1qi  | grep -o '^ *[0-9]*' | wc -l
```

What counting code is more reliable than Example #2?

```
ls -1qi  | grep -o '^ *[0-9]*' | wc -l
```

Count code means, correctly:

- Count directories
- Count regular files
- Count symbolic links
- Count hidden files
- Count and display a file name with spaces
- Count and display a file name with a new line
- Count in one (1) directory
- Count recursively

Said another way: To count files, what is a reliable code (dependable code)?

Comment: Use the tree command, it counts files and directories.

Comment: Command 'tree' not found, but can be installed with: ```sudo snap install tree``` Ideal solution would be portable that has commands with the ISO = **Ubuntu 20.04.3** which is understood to mean the built-in commands that come with bash50171$ meaning GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).  If 'tree' was used then must install it on every computer to run code.

Answer (score 2):

#### Analysis

`ls` with `-1` and `-q` is not the worst way to count files *in some cases*. Both options are defined in the [POSIX specification of `ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), you can call them portable.

The standard ["do not parse `ls`" article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) fights the idea of using `ls` to get filename(s) reliably. If you want to count entries then you don't really need filenames and sometimes carefully used `ls` may work for you. There are general problems though:

1. To tell apart regular files from symlinks or directories you need to use `-l` and to examine [`drwxr-xr-x` or similar string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59132/108618). If you want to tell apart hidden from non-hidden at the same time (and you use `-a` to print hidden files) then you need to check if there is a dot at the beginning of the filename. It's not trivial with `-l` because [a dot with totally different meaning may appear earlier in the line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102624/108618). Yes, `ls -p` can help with spotting directories without `-l`, but this only works for directories. And there is `ls -F` that can be kinda helpful. Depending on what files you want to count, different options for `ls` along with different patterns for `grep` are needed. This may turn ugly quite fast. Note an approach like this is exactly what we mean by "parsing" in this context: analyzing some possibly convoluted structure to get the information you need. This leads us to the main problem.
2. **The output of `ls` is not designed to be parsed.** It is designed to be easily readable by humans. Parsing `ls` is like hammering a screw. In some cases the end result may be acceptable but the hammer is not for this.
3. If you get used to parsing the output of `ls` in cases where it can work then you will be more eager to parse `ls` in cases where it cannot work reliably. [If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

---

#### Basic solution: `find`

What is the right replacement for `ls` here? IMO it's [`find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), Let's build an example command from scratch and analyze some quirks.

First of all, the default action in `find` is `-print`. It prints pathnames to stdout as newline-terminated strings. If the pathname itself contains at least one newline character then there will be more lines than files. This means `find . | wc -l` is not a good way to count all [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). The right portable way is:

```
# count all files `find' can find, starting from `.', recursively 
find . -exec printf a \; | wc -c
```

where `a` can be any one-byte character. For each file `find` finds (including `.`!), one byte is printed; `wc -c` counts these bytes (you can as well print fixed lines and count lines). The downside is `-exec` spawns a separate `printf` process for every file, this is costly, this is slow. With GNU `find` you can make `find` itself do the job of `printf`:

```
find . -printf a | wc -c
```

The above command should perform better, it's not portable though. A portable and probably improved approach is to use the `printf` builtin of your `sh`:

```
# count all files `find' can find, starting from `.', recursively
find . -exec sh -c 'for f do printf a; done' find-sh {} + | wc -c
```

With [this approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195939/108618) one `sh` will process many pathnames and call `printf a` for each. There may be more than one `sh` spawned (to avoid `argument list too long` error, `find` is that smart), still way less than one per pathname. (Note: `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690))

I wrote "*probably* improved approach" because `printf` may or may not be a [builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11454/108618) in your `sh`. If it's not a builtin then the command will perform slightly worse than the one with `-exec printf …`. In practice `printf` is a builtin in basically any implementation of `sh`. Still formally this is not required.

---

#### Magic begins – adding tests

`find` is well equipped to perform various tests on files it visits. Want to count regular files? Here:

```
# count all regular files `find' can find, staring from `.', recursively
find . -type f \
       -exec sh -c 'for f do printf a; done' find-sh {} + | wc -c
```

Hidden files? Here:

```
# count all hidden files `find' can find, starting from `.', recursively
find "$PWD" -name '.*' \
            -exec sh -c 'for f do printf a; done' find-sh {} + | wc -c
```

Note if I used `find . …` then the current working directory would match `-name '.*'` regardless of its "real" name. I used ([properly quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)) `$PWD` to make `find` recognize the current working directory under its "real" name.

You can combine tests. Hidden regular files? Here:

```
# count all hidden regular files `find' can find, starting from `.', recursively
find "$PWD" -type f -name '.*' \
            -exec sh -c 'for f do printf a; done' find-sh {} + | wc -c
```

You can test virtually anything. Remember `-exec foo … \;` is also a test, it succeeds iff `foo` returns exit status `0`; this way you can build custom tests ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1221882/432690)).

The downside is `find` is not easy to master. Common surprises:

- [`-o`](https://superuser.com/a/1387985/432690),
- [rounding (in some tests)](https://superuser.com/a/1351674/432690),
- [unintuitive meaning of `-n`, `n` and `+n` (in some tests)](https://superuser.com/a/1226002/432690).

You may find [this answer of mine useful](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690) (especially "theory" and "pitfalls"). Simple tests like `-type f` are quite straightforward though.

Then there is the recursiveness. `find .` finds `.` and everything below. In GNU `find` one can use `-mindepth 1` to omit the starting point(s), similarly `-maxdepth 1` suppresses descending into subdirectories. In other words GNU `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` should find what `ls -A` prints. I believe BSD `find` uses `-depth 1` for this (note `-depth n` is very different than `-depth`). All these are not portable. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372/108618) provides a portable solution:

> Generally though, it's depth 1 you want (`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`) as you don't want to consider `.` (depth 0), and then it's even simpler:
>
> ```
> find . ! -name . -prune -extra-conditions-and-actions
> ```

And this leads us to the following example:

```
# count all hidden regular files `find' can find, inside `.', non-recursively
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -name '.*' \
         -exec sh -c 'for f do printf a; done' find-sh {} + | wc -c
```

Note it's safe to use `.` here (no need for `$PWD`) because `.` does not pass `! -name .` and therefore the fact it matches `-name '.*'` is irrelevant. Actually if we used `$PWD`, we would complicate things because we would need to replace `! -name .` with something else and in general this would be non-trivial.

One big difference between `ls … | … | wc -l` and any our `find … | wc -c` is: with `find` *we don't parse anything*. Our tests in `find` test directly what we want to test, not some textual representation of it; they don't rely on our understanding of the output format of any tool (like `ls` or whatever). Pathnames with spaces, newlines or whatever cannot break things because they never appear in anything we process.

Another important difference is the ability of `find` to run virtually any test.

---

#### Magic continues – multiple counters

We know how to count files matching virtually any criteria. Each of the commands we used in the previous section gives us a *single* number. If we wanted two numbers, e.g. the total number of files and the number of regular files, then we could run two different `find … | wc -c` commands. This would be sub-optimal because:

- each `find` would traverse the directory tree on its own; caching in the OS may mitigate the problem, but still;
- if something creates regular files in the meantime, it may happen you will find more regular files than files in total; each number will be in some sense correct *at the time it is calculated*, yet as a tuple they won't make sense.

For these reasons one may want a single `find` to give us two (or more) numbers somehow.

Note: from now on I don't bother myself with stopping `find .` from testing `.` itself or from being recursive. Additionally for brevity I will use non-portable `-printf` (that works in GNU `find`) where I need it; the examples way above should suffice if you need a portable equivalent.

This (sub-optimal) code counts the total number of files and the number of regular files, using one `find`:

```
find . -printf 'files total\n' \
       -type f -printf 'regular files\n' \
| sort | uniq -c
```

And this (sub-optimal) code counts the number of directories, the number of regular files, the number of symlinks, finally other files:

```
find . \( -type d -printf 'directories\n' \) \
    -o \( -type f -printf 'regular files\n' \) \
    -o \( -type l -printf 'symlinks\n' \) \
    -o -printf 'of other types\n' \
| sort | uniq -c
```

It's sub-optimal because there are at least three problems with it:

- The counting is performed by `uniq -c`, it needs prior `sort`. But in general you can count things without sorting: you see a thing of some type and you increase the respective counter. If the directory tree is huge then `sort` will do a lot of work. It will be good to replace `sort | uniq -c` with some tool(s) more fitted for the job.
- The final sequence of lines depends on how `sort` sorts strings first. You will probably prefer `other types` in the last line of output, but we cannot easily affect the sequence.
- If there are no symlinks at all then there will be no line stating `0 symlinks`. Suppose you see `2 of other types` and no line mentioning symlinks. Then it's natural to assume "other types" include symlinks, but this is not true.

With `awk` we can solve all the three problems:

```
find . \( -type d -printf 'd\n' \) \
    -o \( -type f -printf 'f\n' \) \
    -o \( -type l -printf 'l\n' \) \
    -o -printf 'o\n' \
| awk '
    BEGIN {count["d"]=0; count["f"]=0; count["l"]=0; count["o"]=0}
    {count[$0]++}
    END {
      printf("%s directories\n", count["d"])
      printf("%s regular files\n", count["f"])
      printf("%s symlinks\n", count["l"])
      printf("%s of other types\n", count["o"])
      print "------"
      printf("%s files total\n", count["d"]+count["f"]+count["l"]+count["o"])
    }'
```

Now we are in control of what our code prints. We can even make it print lines like `N_DIRS=123` and `eval` the output in a shell script, so shell variables are created to be used later in the script.

Note how I used `awk` to sum four numbers. I could make `find` *additionally* print `t` (like "total") for any single file and count appearances of `t` with `awk`, then I wouldn't need to sum in `awk`. My point is the general scheme is quite flexible. It's basically this:

1. `find` performs tests of our choice and prints tokens (lines) of our choice. A file may generate zero, one or more tokens, depending on what we want. Obviously the more you are familiar with `find`, the more complex logic you can code without bugs.
2. `awk` counts how many times each token appears.
3. `awk` may do additional calculations.
4. `awk` prints the result, using format of our choice.

---

#### Even more complex code, shell function

The following function never tests `.` (because I think usually you don't want to count the current working directory). It's recursive when invoked as `count -R`, non-recursive otherwise. If needed, get rid of non-portable `-printf` like we did earlier in this answer.

```
# should work in sh
count() (
   unset IFS
   if [ "$1" = -R ]; then
      arg=''
   else
      arg='-prune'
   fi

   find . ! -name . $arg \( \
         \( -type d \( -name '.*' -printf 'dh\n' -o -printf 'dn\n' \) \) \
      -o \( -type f \( -name '.*' -printf 'fh\n' -o -printf 'fn\n' \) \) \
      -o \( -type l \( -name '.*' -printf 'lh\n' -o -printf 'ln\n' \) \) \
      -o \(            -name '.*' -printf 'oh\n' -o -printf 'on\n' \) \
                         \) \
   | awk '
      BEGIN {
         count["dn"]=0; count["dh"]=0
         count["fn"]=0; count["fh"]=0
         count["ln"]=0; count["lh"]=0
         count["on"]=0; count["oh"]=0
      }
      {  count[$0]++ }
      END {
         tn=count["dn"]+count["fn"]+count["ln"]+count["on"]
         th=count["dh"]+count["fh"]+count["lh"]+count["oh"]
         t=tn+th
         printf("%9d directories    (%9d non-hidden, %9d hidden)\n", count["dn"]+count["dh"], count["dn"], count["dh"])
         printf("%9d regular files  (%9d non-hidden, %9d hidden)\n", count["fn"]+count["fh"], count["fn"], count["fh"])
         printf("%9d symlinks       (%9d non-hidden, %9d hidden)\n", count["ln"]+count["lh"], count["ln"], count["lh"])
         printf("%9d of other types (%9d non-hidden, %9d hidden)\n", count["on"]+count["oh"], count["on"], count["oh"])
         print "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
         printf("%9d files total    (%9d non-hidden, %9d hidden)\n", t, tn, th)
    }'
)
```

I guess the `awk` code is less elegant than it could be; and I'm not really sure if it's totally portable (I haven't studied the [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) thoroughly).

In general [one should double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) variables like `$arg`, but here we need `$arg` to disappear when empty. Possible values are safe, unless the `$IFS` contains any character appearing in the string `-prune`. I deliberately designed the function to always run in a subshell (`f() (…)` syntax instead of `f() {…}`) where I `unset IFS` to make sure the unquoted `$arg` will always work.

Example output:

```
$ count -R
    40130 directories    (    40043 non-hidden,        87 hidden)
   363974 regular files  (   362220 non-hidden,      1754 hidden)
     6797 symlinks       (     6793 non-hidden,         4 hidden)
       25 of other types (       25 non-hidden,         0 hidden)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   410926 files total    (   409081 non-hidden,      1845 hidden)
```

Comment: Most undervalued answer on SU.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework problem (a little too well defined).

My suggestion is:

```
find . -printf %i\\n | wc -l
```

It doesn't use 'ls', but that's because 'ls' is aimed at user-parseable output, and 'find' is aimed at programmatic use.  If you are trying to use 'ls', ask yourself why.