# Converting 'if elif fi' to 'case esac' statement while using Bash test operators

Tags: bash

I have the following code which works:

```
for file in $(find $1 -maxdepth 10000 -xdev -ignore_readdir_race); do
    if [[ "$file" =~ ^($OP0|$OP1|$OP2|$OP3|$OP4|$OP5|$OP6|$OP7|$OP8|$OP9)$ ]]; then (( SkipCnt++ )) # Count of skipped files
        elif [[ ! -e "$file" ]] ; then (( StalCnt++ ))                      # Count of files that existed last run, but don't now
        elif [[ ! -s "$file" ]] ; then (( ZeroCnt++ ))                      # Count of zero sized files
        elif [[ -d "$file" ]] ; then (( DirCnt++ ))                         # Count of directories
        elif [[ -h "$file" || -L "$file" ]] ; then (( LinkCnt++ ))          # Count of symbolic links
        elif [[ -c "$file" ]] ; then (( CdevCnt++ ))                        # Count of character devices
        elif [[ -b "$file" ]] ; then (( BdevCnt++ ))                        # Count of block devices
        elif [[ -p "$file" ]] ; then (( PipeCnt++ ))                        # Count of pipes
        elif [[ -S "$file" ]] ; then (( SockCnt++ ))                        # Count of sockets
        elif [[ -f "$file" && -s "$file" ]] ; then                          # File must exist, and not be any of the above.

# You can use any one of these three, listed fastest to slowest
            tar -cS --no-recursion --warning=none "$file" &>/dev/null
            # cp --preserve=all --reflink=never "$file" /dev/null
            # cat "$file" 1>/dev/null

            (( FileCnt++ ))                                                 # Count of files cache-loaded
        else
            (( SkipCnt++ ))                                                 # Count of any files not otherwise processed.
    fi
```

I'm attempting to convert it to a case statement, but I can't figure it out... what I've got so far (I just copied each if statement to the case statement, but it keeps throwing an error):

The error:

```
/usr/local/bin/cachewarmup: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `"$file"'
/usr/local/bin/cachewarmup: line 43: `          [[ "$file" =~ ^($OP0|$OP1|$OP2|$OP3|$OP4|$OP5|$OP6|$OP7|$OP8|$OP9)$ ]]) (( SkipCnt++ ));;'
```

The (non-working) code:

```
for file in $(find $1 -maxdepth 10000 -xdev -ignore_readdir_race); do
    case true in
            [[ "$file" =~ ^($OP0|$OP1|$OP2|$OP3|$OP4|$OP5|$OP6|$OP7|$OP8|$OP9)$ ]]) (( SkipCnt++ ));;
            [[ ! -e "$file" ]]) (( StalCnt++ ));;
            [[ ! -s "$file" ]]) (( ZeroCnt++ ));;
            [[ -d "$file" ]]) (( DirCnt++ ));;
            [[ -h "$file" || -L "$file" ]]) (( LinkCnt++ ));;
            [[ -c "$file" ]]) (( CdevCnt++ ));;
            [[ -b "$file" ]]) (( BdevCnt++));;
            [[ -p "$file" ]]) (( PipeCnt++));;
            [[ -S "$file" ]]) (( SockCnt++ ));;
            [[ -f "$file" && -s "$file" ]]) tar -cS --no-recursion --warning=none "$file" &>/dev/null; (( FileCnt++ ));;
            *) (( SkipCnt++ ));;
    esac
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `case` is the wrong thing to use here. `case` is for comparing a single string (emphasis: *string*, not boolean value, bash doesn't have booleans) to a series of patterns (or specific values), not for testing general conditions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your case of `if` and `case`

`case something in` interprets `something` as a string, not as a command. It makes little sense (if any at all) for `something` to be a *fixed* string like `true`.

Usually a variable is used there. It provides a non-fixed string that gets compared to pattern(s) present later in code.

In the logic of your original code there is no such variable. Your tests are *commands* (well, `[[` is a shell keyword, not strictly a command; but it's still something that returns exit status like a command, totally not a string). If all the commands tried to compare the value of a certain variable to some patterns then probably they could be converted to `case … esac`. Among your commands the one with `=~` does this, but the rest do something else. This does not really qualify to be converted to `case … esac`.

In general even tests with `=~` may *or may not* qualify to be converted to `case … esac`. The problem is `=~` uses a regex, while patterns for `case` are not regular expressions; in general it may be impossible to convert one scheme to the other strictly.

Stick to `if … elif … fi`, do not try to convert to syntax that does not fit.

---

#### Broader view on `if` and `case`

`if` depends on the exit status of some shell code that returns exit status. It may be a command (like `grep` or `[`) or something else (like `[[` or a pipeline) that returns exit status like a command would. Basically after `if` (or `elif`) you can put *arbitrary* shell code as a condition.

`case` directly compares *strings*. It does not rely on the exit status of anything. While in principle you can convert string comparison (`case`) to shell code that implements the same string comparison (for `if`), converting *arbitrary* shell code (`if`) to string comparison (`case`) is cumbersome (if possible at all).

---

#### Side notes

- The first line of your code is the [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).
- Unquoted `$1` [makes things worse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).
- [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1687310/432690) is how I use `find` to count files of different types.

Comment: Don't all of the 'if elif' statements resolve to either true or false? That's sort of the point of 'if', isn't it? And the code isn't just counting files, it's copying certain files to /dev/null to warm up the ZFS cache... how do I do that with the suggested find "$1" -exec some command {} \;?

Comment: @PyNewbie You can interpret `if` this way. The point is you cannot interpret `case` this way.

Comment: @PyNewbie "how do I do that with the suggested `find "$1" -exec …`?" – This is a separate question. Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work. We won't fix your entire script in one thread. If you can divide your problems with the script to a set of well-defined questions then possibly we can fix it eventually over multiple posts. Here the question is about `if` to `case` conversion specifically. My side notes are just side notes to point you in the right direction. If you want help beyond `if` to `case` conversion then you should ask new question(s).

Comment: @PyNewbie "Don't all of the 'if elif' statements resolve to either true or false?" – It really depends on what you mean by "true" and "false". In a shell the string `true` is nothing special. *If* it's interpreted and executed as a command then it returns exit status `0`. `false` as a command returns exit status `1`. The exit status of *some* command is what matters to `if`, so `if true; then` is valid (but not really useful). Instead of `true` there can be any other command-like entity, e.g. `[[ … ]]`. OTOH `case` directly compares strings, it does not rely on exit status of anything.